# Dashboard x axis name remove

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, dashboard

I have a salesforce dashboard absolutely perfect for me as shown in picture attached. Only thing is I want to remove this text : **`Time Off Territory Detail : RecordType`**

Can someone please let me know if that's feasible and how?
[image]

Please find image of the report here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using the charts created on Dashboards.

However if you create the chart in Report itself and use that chart in Dashboard, you will have an option on that chart to show/hide the axis labels.

> Edit the report chart -> Go to Formatting tab -> Uncheck 'Show Axis
>   Label' checkbox.

**EDIT:**

`Show values` option comes when you create the chart in dashboard itself and not use the chart created on report. So you should first add a chart on your report(which you already have, based on the screenshot you added in the question) and then in your dashboard just add the report and use the same chart like this:

[image]

This is a snapshot of what I see when I edit the report chart(not dashboard chart).

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: the chart  is in report itself.

Comment: Please find the report how it looks like in the updated question.

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to hide the axis label.

Comment: I am sorry there is only Show values checkbox

Comment: I am quite sure you are using dashboard chart, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! It serves my purpose! I will never forget this use!!

Comment: I was able to depict the case but then the legend position shifting to bottom doesn't work. One more thing is to show "Hours" along the y-axis. I got my question perfectly answered with your help. these two just added things needed. That's not possible as I make out isn't it?

Comment: Reg. the legend position, I believe you still have the option when you edit the report chart, see just above my highlighted portion in the image in my answer.  Next, if hours is a number field in the same record as Vacation, Personal etc, I believe you can do it. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Perfectly done! Hours is not number field actually there is no field for hours. Its the unit for other number fields. Anyways, I made Dashboard title as Hours which somehow looks like depicting y-axis  :P Its fine as of now. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Glad, I could help! :)